# Transparent skin-tight clothes

Tags: modeling, materials, shrinkwrap

Whole problem mentioned in a title. I want to model and, what's more important, animate character with skin-tight cloth like semi-transparent stockings or bodysuit. The main problems are overlapping and/or solidify thickness (that's looks really funny in some cases :). Maybe someone knows if there is a trick for such cases like subsurface scattering or something? Or there's no magic pill for that?

Comment: If the cloths should have practically no thickness, why don't you use texture in body material for that?

Comment: Good idea, but what about parts like fingers, toes, belly button,  etc. How to deal with them to keep the feeling of real cloth?